# Running script on both local and remote machines?

Tags: python

In my Python code, I have something similar to the following:

```
data = load_data()

results = model.train(data)

show_graph(results)
```

Here, `load_data()` loads some data from my local machine, and `show_graph(results)` shows a graph on my local machine. However, `model.train(data)` needs to be executed on a remote machine, because it requires specialist hardware. I only want to run this one function on the remote machine, not the entire script.

I have a user account on this remote machine, and can login using, for example, `ssh user@remote.ip.address`.

But how can I tell my script to run a certain function on this remote machine?

Comment: See https://wiki.python.org/moin/ParallelProcessing

Comment: how does `load_data()` get data from your local machine? Say you do `ssh` into the remote machine, would `load_data()` successfully load data from the remote machine?

Comment: zeroc ICE is the best answer to your question. Via ICE you can run method on object residing on host elsewhere. BTW the method (or function) you calling can be implemented on language different from python. https://zeroc.com

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of `RPC` stack (although I'm kind of certain that something can be made by using `celery` and a little tweaking). A good option (as good as any other) is to implement a server using [grpc](http://www.grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/python.html), it will also allow you to use different languages for the client and the server.